# Underwater life on a 3G world

Tags: xenobiology, underwater, life

I'm creating a 3G ocean world and am wondering how the heavier gravity would affect life under this ocean?

Comment: Can you limit yourself to one specific question. You're currently asking 3 questions, "How would an increased gravity affect life?", "What life would evolve?" and "Would the increase in gravity affect buoyancy?".  Given all the different varieties of underwater live on our planet, it seems like the number of potentially valid answers for this question is going to be particularly broad.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: What @sphennings said. And, in addition, please clarify what you mean by "what kind" of life would evolve.

Comment: In addition - welcome to worldbuilding. Please enjoy our wonderful [tour] and refer to the [help] for guidance as necessary.

Comment: OH, I apologize.  Thank you for your advice on questions, and for your welcome!